# Using Django cms for editable webpage?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am currently working on a website using Django. Here's my issue. I want some pages of my website to be partially editable (just text edition) by registered users. And I want it to be user friendly enough. 
I first thought of using regular html forms to make the content editable. And then I discovered Django CMS. As far as I understand I can pretty much do what I want with Django CMS. But I am wondering if it's not too heavy in this situation, and I want to have a lot of control on what I make editable or not by the users. 
Therefore my questions are :

Should I use Django CMS or not ?

If yes, would it be possible to restrict the standard usage of Django CMS depending on the logged user ? (For example, I mean by that, just allowing the user to edit a paragraph, and not to modifying the whole layout of the page)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Django CMS, but if all you want to do is let them edit a plain text chunk on a web page, plain old Django can do that without breaking a sweat. Django admin can be used to handle editing at the very least, and you just need a model with a `TextField` to store the text, and a template to render it into an HTML page. You could probably figure out how to do it after working through the Django tutorial.

Comment: Or use the Flatpages app.